# Find and Exclude one Matrix from other

Tags: matlab, matrix, discrete-mathematics, set-difference

I'm working on MATLAB. I have the following matrices

```
A = [
    1 2 3 4
    5 6 7 8
    1 5 2 3
    6 7 8 9
    1 3 6 2
    6 3 1 6
    9 7 4 7
];

B = [
    1 5 2 3
    6 7 8 9
];
```

I want to find `A`-`B`
so that the answer should be like,

```
ans = [
    1 2 3 4
    5 6 7 8
    1 3 6 2
    6 3 1 6
    9 7 4 7
];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`setdiff`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setdiff.html) with the `'rows'` and `'stable'` options:

```
>> C = setdiff(A,B,'rows','stable')
C =
     1     2     3     4
     5     6     7     8
     1     3     6     2
     6     3     1     6
     9     7     4     7
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [ismember](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) to find the common rows and neglect those in the final `output`.

**Code**

```
out = A(~ismember(A,B,'rows'),:)
```

**Output**

```
out =

     1     2     3     4
     5     6     7     8
     1     3     6     2
     6     3     1     6
     9     7     4     7
```

Answer (score 0):

[@Divakar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22462878/2586922) or [@chappjc's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22462898/2586922) answers are the way to go.

But I can't help inviting [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) to the party:

```
C = A(~any(squeeze(all(bsxfun(@eq, A.', permute(B, [2 3 1])))).'),:);
```

And its friend [`pdist2`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/stats/pdist2.html) is coming too:

```
C = A(all(pdist2(A, B, 'hamming').'),:);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
clear;
s=0;
A = [

    1 2 3 4
    5 6 7 8
    1 5 2 3
    6 7 8 9
    1 3 6 2
    6 3 1 6
    9 7 4 7
];

B = [

    1 5 2 3
    6 7 8 9
];

for i=1:size(B)

s=s+(ismember(A, B(i,:), 'rows'))

end

A_B = A(s==0,:)
```